# Date query in SSRS

Tags: date, reporting-services

I currently use the expressions:

```
=today.adddays(1-today.day)

=Today.AddDays(1-Today.Day).AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1)
```

to get the first and last day of the current month (last day I need to include seconds).

Is there a way of tweaking these expressions to bring through the first day and the last day (inc seconds) of the previous month?

So for example the required output for expression 1 would be:

```
01/11/2017
```

For expression2 it would be:

```
30/11/2017 23:59:59
```

Any advice gratefully accepted.

Thanks

Comment: If all you want is what you currently have, but a month earlier, can't you just append another `AddMonths(-1)` to the existing expressions? (or put it wherever else in the expression you want, if you prefer how that looks)

Comment: ah yes. cheers. couldn't see for looking. Thanks for your time - appreciated.

Comment: Of course, note that cancels out the `AddMonths(1)` in your 2nd expression, so you can just omit both.